# Internationalization and Localization of Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, localization, internationalization

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Other language localization](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/other-language-localization)
>   [Wikipedia Style Localization](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1506/wikipedia-style-localization)

By the popularity of SO, does our Stack Overflow team has any ideas about internationalizing and localizing stackoverflow.com?

It would be interesting to know what languages they would consider for internationalization.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39646/possible-positive-effects-of-vc-funding-for-stackoverflow/39649#39649 Read the answer by George Stocker and the comments

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/other-language-localization and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1506/wikipedia-style-localization and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32776/localized-versions-of-stackoverflow

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42544/provide-some-kind-of-on-the-fly-translation-e-g-french-to-english

Answer (score 0):

This has been rejected several times and in several ways.

Here's my proposal ( now that I read it again it does look confusing )

[Add meta-tag to support internationalization](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3774/add-meta-tag-to-support-internationalization)

But in summary is: "Allow **content** in any language, and let the user filter like if it was a tag. Default language is English"

This way I may see Spanish and English content, but not Japanese or Russian.

Well that was rejected.

Jeff summarized the reasons here:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Basically ( and in my own words ) the reasons are:

- English is the lingua franca of programming.
- If you want to ask in other language, go somewhere else.

This is a shame, but that's the current state.

I hope that eventually that change. As for now, just forget it.

Comment: If you think about it, PHP uses english words for functions .... I'm sure a lot of other languages (programming ones that is) also use english as the language of choice for keywords.

Comment: @Chacha102: the language of choice for keywords, but not necessarily for programming questions.

Comment: as well, if english is not your first language, nuances in english function names might escape you and give rise to questions on SO-type sites.  what better way to have the nuance described to you than in your own tongue.

Comment: @Chacha101 : Not really, it doesn't matter how good your English is, you won't be able to make `C` understand this `a is 3; when a is 3 print Hi;` Not even if you add *please* because THAT's NOT ENGLISH is C.  You don't learn the natural language when you learn to program; you learn the **programming** language.  I learn `C` when I was 18 and knew very very little English, and for me `for, while, switch, goto, typedef` meant nothing in English, but they had a meaning in `C`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202723/coding-in-other-spoken-languages/202851#202851