# Can I post in more than one language?

Tags: discussion, languages, posts

Am I allowed to post in two or more languages? For example, if I see on a user profile that the user is Dutch, is it okay if I answer the question in both English **and** Dutch?

**Example:**

> English:
> This is an example of my question.
>
> ---
>
> Dutch/Nederlands:
> Dit is een voorbeeld van mijn vraag.

Comment: [math.se] has french + english questions quite often. Noone will understand dutch at [so], however.

Comment: You can do that in comments if you want. (but this will also be removed at some point)

Comment: @JanDvorak: Spreek voor jezelf / Speak for yourself. That said, I *will* edit it out of posts.. Comments are a different matter, if used sparingly (I'd only use it for quick yibes to show that I happen to be Dutch too, if at all).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140613/152859

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The site language is English.

Writing in any other language (even repeating the answer) is likely to get edited out by the community.

It is nice that you want to connect with the OP in their native language, however - most users of the site will not understand it.

In other words - it is allowed, but will be considered noise by most users, therefore probably removed.

Answer (score 7):

Nee, dat is niet toegestaan/No, that's not allowed. Or not allowed ... there's just no point (even more so for a tiny language like Dutch) and it's kind of noisy.

Just post your question in the language of the site. And in most cases that is English. There might be sites in other languages (Like the Portuguese SO that exists now, or the various language sites) but until then, just stick to a single language.

Comment: [math.se] allows french+english questions as well.

Comment: Seems an exception to the rule then @JanDvorak? (Except of course for language specific sites)

Comment: @JanDvorak That's because they have certain French information source that are very useful ([source](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12253)). <s>We can't say the same about programming and the Dutch language.</s>

Comment: *cough* Edsger Wybe Dijkstra *cough* @Stijn.

Comment: @Stijn: Unless you happen to use Python, perhaps. At least the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) is hinting it might help.. (the Python language creator is Dutch).

Comment: @Bart I know who that is but I'm not familiar with his papers. Are they mainly in Dutch?

Comment: Several of his early [EWD's](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/) are in Dutch, yes. And his Dutch is the reason behind the P and V in semaphores for example @Stijn.