# Where can I translate the Stack Exchange UI into German?

Tags: feature-request, languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Localization: The state of the nation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82176/localization-the-state-of-the-nation)

I want translate it in the German language. Where can I do it?

It is needed for the German community.

[Ubuntufrage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30384)