# Will Area 51 be supported in the app?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, android-app, area-51

Will [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) be supported on the Android App in the future? I visit A51 rather frequently and I would like to see it in the App.

Comment: My same response to everything else related to Area 51: probably not until they rebuild it. They don't even have a mobile web version of Area 51...

Comment: So, you are basically saying [6-8 arbitrary units of time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82229/200868).

Comment: Please implement a mobile version and make it available in android app

Comment: @animuson I suppose now they have a mobile web version of A51? Or I guess, it's no different from the desktop version but it was written well enough that it looks fairly decent on my Chrome for Android on smartphone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I won't go so far as to say "never" here, but the odds are pretty low that Area 51 in its current form will receive a native mobile app experience.

Comment: Is the iOS app any different? [New request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220532/152859), same issue?

Comment: Guess nothing has changed, three years later?

Comment: Admitting my incompetence about your project goals and resource grouping, I would like to mention [an argument for the further development of the A51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296587/259412).