# Add Area 51 Meta to the app

Tags: feature-request, area-51, android-app

I came across something rather interesting today. I was browsing Area 51 on Chrome when I happened to click on [a discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9984/70968). To this, I was greeted with a prompt asking:

[image: Huhh!]

As [Area 51 is not supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194896/200868), and fully expecting a crash, I clicked on SE. However, that didnt happen.

[image]
[image]

Now, since Area 51 Meta is working correctly as far as Q&A is concerned, I think it should be added to the All Sites list and if at all possible, made directly browsable from within the app.

Comment: If by "*working correctly*" means you can browse and read the post, then yes I agree. Otherwise, it's broken since we can't join & create an account  (to post/comment/vote) from the app.

Comment: Its not even in my menu

Comment: The same here, saying that I'm _not a member of Unknown Site_. Then the app crashed when clicking on the link.