# Cannot open Area 51 while there is a banner in the Android app feed

Tags: bug, area-51, android-app

Seems like missing feature, but why placing a banner inside the app to the site if it isn't supported?

The app gives "*Failed to load data*".

Comment: AFAIK, the Area 51 banner has gone since quite long time. However, for the feature request, refer to [Will Area 51 be supported in the app?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194896/will-area-51-be-supported-in-the-app)