# A click on the banner should go to Area51 *inside* the app, not from the default browser

Tags: feature-request, area-51, ios-app

There is a banner at the top of the page "feeds". At the moment, this banner show up the Area51. But when I click on it, it launch Chrome to view the page. It should go to the Area51 *inside* the app.

[image: banner]

Comment: I would presume that some ads need to be pure http links to go offsite for advertisements where actual paid apps are run (SO, SF, etc...) and that this would be a request for the app to be able to detect the subset of ad content that could be redirected within the app assuming it registers for URL handlers or can change the processing in a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Can you view Area51 in the app in some other way? As far as I remember the android app doesn't support it yet due to its different engine so assume the iOS app got the same restriction. [See this as reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194896/152859). :/

Comment: From my understanding the android app does not support area51 and does not have plans to support it beacuse of differences in area51 versus the rest of the stack exchange network. Here is a link to a question about area 51 and the android app. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194896/will-area-51-be-supported-in-the-app