# Area 51 does not work via the android app

Tags: bug, android-app

Area 51 is not available via the android app. It does not appear in the list of sites.

I have noticed that comments on example questions do however trigger an app notification.

is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that one. Just wish my tablet would stop asking me to load the site in the app then when I click on links.

Comment: @NickJAdams Me too. Handling link redirection to the app is a big pain point since all of our links are of the form *.stackexchange.com -- The app also thinks it can handle chat links :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The team [isn't going](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212420/259214) to make Area 51 available in the android app yet :( . It is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)