# Translate some question/answer into other language

Tags: discussion, languages, non-english-speakers

I am a user of Stack Overflow and Server Fault.

I am from Belgium. I really like using the Stack websites because it is easy to find help. Now I have made an account and I can ask a question but my English isn't very good. I known English is very important in I.T., but:

- I just want known if it is possible to flag my question to know I am not an native English speaker;
- If it's possible to add functionality to allow user to translate a question or answer into another Language. Because when I started to develop I didn't understand any post. I'm not talking about simply posting like "How to open a file in C++", but for example about "What is polymorphism, is it useful?"

I have found this [Non-English Question Policy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) and wonder if this functionality will ever be developed? I think it is bad because the question / answer will be the same, but in other language.

This post [Localization: The state of the nation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82176/localization-the-state-of-the-nation) spoke about my ideas, but I just want to translate some question or answer **not all the website**.
Stack Exchange help allow me to increase my English.

Comment: Stack Exchange is working hard these days on creating localized versions of Stack Overflow. So far two emerged, what is your native language? French? Dutch?

Comment: My native language is French

Comment: FYI - there was an Area 51 proposal for a French Stack Overflow, but apparently didn't receive enough attention: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12692/stack-overflow-in-french

Answer (score 6):

Virtually all Stack Exchange sites require you to post in English. There are some language specific versions of Stack Overflow:

[スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) - Stack Overflow in Japanese

[Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) - Stack Overflow in Portuguese

[Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)  - Stack Overflow in Russian

but these have come out of the proposal process on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) so are the ones that most people want. There are other language specific sites in definition but it will take some time before (or indeed if) they are launched.

If non of these fit the bill then I can only suggest that you use an online translation tool to convert your question from your native language to English. If you add a comment to the effect that you're not a native speaker then someone will help you out by correcting any mistakes the automatic translation made. You can do the same for any answer - just convert it to your language if you are struggling to understand. You can always leave comments on answers to your own questions regardless of how little reputation you have, so you can always ask for clarification.

What you shouldn't do is post in your native language and hope that someone will come along and translate it for you.

Comment: Year, It's true. I can use auto translate like 'Google' but when I do that it's because I don't understand the method or philosophy of question.Auto translator make awful grammar and it's more difficult to understand. That why I want users are allowed to translate answer. **I understand mostly question but not the answers**.

Comment: @olive007 As a high rep user on [ubuntu.se], if I see a post with broken english I will edit to inprove it. Do your best with it, and keep learning! Google translate is bad, but understandable.