# Can I ask questions on SO in my regional language?

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Localized versions of StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32776/localized-versions-of-stackoverflow)

I want to ask questions or I need to answer in SO with my Regional language.

Is it possible to do?

I know if its possible other ppl will down vote for that isnt it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, please don't. Stack Overflow is an English  language site. There are various proposals on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) for regional language SO-like sites though. Perhaps have a look at those to see if something fits the bill or is worth proposing.

If English is not your first language and you fear you might make some mistakes, don't worry too much. Put in your very best effort, spell check, do whatever you can to get things as close as possible. If it's not utterly terrible and incomprehensible, most likely a member of the community will help you edit it into shape. But don't rely on this. Do as good a job as you can.

Comment: Putting effort means among others writing words full out with proper punctuation, so don't use street/chat talk like writing "its", "ppl" or "isnt" instead of "it's", "people" or "isn't". This way you show with relatively minor effort off having respect for the language.

Comment: @Chichiray: Isn't writing "its" instead of "it's" a spelling mistake and not "chat speech"?

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby I wouldn't call "its vs it's" "chat speech" either, but it is probably more commonly a grammar mistake rather than a spelling mistake.