# Is it possible to internationalize the Stack Exchange UI elements?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, localization

I see that its possible to have questions/answers in any language.
Is it possible to have fully localized user interface as well - all menus, links, buttons etc?
We are looking to build Russian law QA website. Most visitors will not speak English at all.
We'll be happy to help with resources translation if needed (I do realize that is no OS project, though).

FAQ on Area51 links to meta.stackoverflow.com but it seems that meta.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask questions on StackExcange engine not specific to StackOverflow.
Here's good localization question to be voted for instead of this one: [Is the fastest gun in the west solved?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/what-localization-features-does-stackexchange-have)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to find out. From your first sentence, I assume you already know about proposals like the Persian IT one that Ether mentioned. But I thought that site was going to include a localized interface. Could you clarify, please?

Comment: @Popular Demand I am probably just missing something. When I see that (Persian IT) in Area51 - I see all interface elements are in English (links, menus, button captions etc) but they also have a link to some standalone website (in header) - and its in Persian (not sure). I'm not sure if it is related to StackExchange site on Are51 or just separate one.

Comment: I think it's just an external site giving more details of the proposal.  That said, the feature request is sound -- the Stack Exchange UI elements should be localizable.

Comment: right, Area 51 is not localized, but I was under the impression that the final site will be. I could be wrong, though; I can't remember why I think that, and I can't find any sources to back me up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Other language localization](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/other-language-localization)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the moment

Comment: I guess your answer is correct - should I mark it? Will my question still be treated as feature request? will people be able to vote for it?

Comment: @Igor: 1. yes, if you feel it answered your question (it did). 2. yes, since you've tagged it as a `feature-request`. 3. yes.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a [proposal for a site in Persian](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2912/persian-information-technology-and-computer), I would say yes, this is allowed.

Comment: No, I need all elements of UI to be localized: "Ask Question" -> "Задать Вопрос"

Comment: @Igor: ah, sorry, I totally misunderstood your question then! :)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is only possible via Google Translate integration or by means of changing UI elements directly with JavaScript. Details are here: [Is the fastest gun in the west solved?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/what-localization-features-does-stackexchange-have)

Answer (score 0):

This may be coming sooner than you think.

[Other language localization](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/other-language-localization/51370#51370)