# Auto revision summary has wrong plural: "added 1 characters in body"

Tags: bug, status-declined, revisions-list, plurals

As seen at: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3847048/revisions

> [image: added 1 characters in body]

---

**Update:** I'm 101% sure the down votes were due to the lack of free hands.

---

**Update 2:** likes me, like me not, like me, likes me not... yeah [like me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694)!

Comment: That hand is almost Ridgey Didge

Comment: @random: does you means your left hands look exactly like these?

Comment: Please review the following meme: [Pluralization Bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["viewed 1 times"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times)

Comment: It's a duplicate symptoms, but I'm 99.99% sure it's not a duplicate code paths.

Comment: Is that a Hook 'Em Horns?

Comment: @mmyers: it's an Excruciatingly-Overstretched-Pinky version of HEH.

Comment: The link to the revisions is now broken. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this probably should have been built into the sites originally, I would rather they fix this when the sites are [enabled for localization](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65115/is-it-possible-to-internationalize-the-stack-exchange-ui-elements/65143#65143). Doing it now would be wasted effort because it would all have to be redone in any localization model.

There are more important bugs to fix than this right now anyway.

Answer (score 15):

From [Jeff Atwood's twitter](http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105):

> Dear Next Person Who Opens a Pluralization 'Bug', I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant S
>   <sub>- 3:33 AM Feb 1st, 2009 via web</sub>

Jeffs comes acrosses as pretty stubborns, I doubts his minds will have changed since then, despites how ridiculously easy this is to implements.

[image]
<sub>(source: [globalnet.co.uk](http://www.users.globalnet.co.uk/~pennck/grabs/salsmall.gif))</sub>

Comment: I thinks Toki from Metalocalypse woulds fit good here, too.

Comment: This gets posted every time someone reports a pluralization bug.. Maybe it's just me but I don't find it very funny

Comment: @Kop, I don't find Jeff's tweet particularly funny but that's mostly because I think this sort of thing needs fixing.  That's why I had Sal help me answer the question - Sal *is* funny ;-)

Answer (score 6):

[image: s]

Comment: Alt tag for image: `S`.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - What is an "alt tag" ?

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco the text describing an image for blind or low bandwidth users. The proper name is "alt attribute". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_attribute

Answer (score 4):

RE [King Atwood's threats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66451/auto-revision-summary-has-wrong-plural-added-1-characters-in-body/66452#66452), I doesn't believes it are going to happens any times soon.

I happens to has two house right now (both of which is under the waters, so please contacts me if you is a mortgage brokers), and I uses a [doubly random](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Random-Stupidity.aspx) random-number generators to decides which houses I stays in at any given times.

And there have been at least [one simliar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times) bugs reported between the King's tweets and my questions. Since the King specifically said "Next Person" without Ss, Sir Isaac Waller would has been the victims by any measures.

I suspects that the King's apparent rages against plurals may stems from his secret [Indonesian heritage-heritage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesian_language#Pluralisation).

Comment: Isaac Waller was last "seen Sep 5 at 18:28"; in other words, it's been _almost a month since we've heard from him_. Just sayin'....