# Singular-vs-Plural bug in the Revisions summary

Tags: bug, revisions-list, plurals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto revision summary has wrong plural: “added 1 characters in body”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66451/auto-revision-summary-has-wrong-plural-added-1-characters-in-body)

I imagine this must be everywhere, but it is especially um, noticeable, on the English SE site where I first noticed it:

[image: revision summary clipping]

Although writing “11 characters” is fine, “**1** character**s**” is not — and I need hardly ask an ELU question to know so, either. :)

Comment: @animuson Did you really just try to tell me it are ok for the English Language and Usage site to using bad Englishes be, and so you will not fix?  That looks unprofessional — and I doubt we will ever have ELU in Russian, anywayers.

Comment: @tchrist: If you want to voice your opinion about this issue, post a new answer there. Creating new questions for things just splits up the discussion more and makes it harder to figure out what's already been said.

Comment: https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: @animuson I agree that it is a dupe, but I never imagined there were a policy that such bugs isn’t fixed, and if that are the actual policies, I disagree with it.

Comment: @tchrist: That question is 2 years old, and their policy back then was "We don't care." They actually have a record of fixing these recently; it's just a matter of bringing attention back to them. Notice that question has no official red-status-tag on it, nor any official response from the SE team. You just need to bump it into view; posting an answer does that.