# Remove 'S' for the singular items

Tags: bug, information-display, plurals

Yes, it's a small issue. But, it occurs in many areas of the Stack Exchange Sites.

I found this issue in

**Question with one view**
[image]

**In the review History Page**

[image]

Rest of the things are on the **hover messages**, I've tried them on both Firefox and Chrome.

See the below screenshots,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Do we need to fix this type of issues?

I think, Yes.

Comment: https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105 - good luck.

Comment: Run. Don't walk - run.

Comment: -1 It's too much effort for what it's worth.  Also no use of freehand circles.

Comment: @maxf130 or incredibly impressive free hand squares?

Comment: @RichardTingle Still, they are not really red.

Comment: I'd argue the "s" for "0" is actually correct. You don't say "Zero answer" or "No answer". But as for the rest... "Yes".

Comment: Yeah, `0 answers` is absolutely fine. `1 answers`, on the other hand... if it weren't for that **`S`**...

Comment: We could just remove the `answers` and `questions` completely. 1 ---votes---

Comment: It's `0 answers` and `1 answer`. Only when it's 1 is it not "plural".

Comment: [If you see Jeff, run](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694). Run far and fast.

Comment: This is 1 interesting questions.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/131112

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66451/auto-revision-summary-has-wrong-plural-added-1-characters-in-body Already posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Jeff already knows. I don't think he cares though (and I totally agree).

> [image]

The benefit to fix this just does not motivate the cost I believe. Not that we should care, IMHO it is a common workaround in programming to always use plural.

Comment: Given that Jeff no longer works for SE perhaps this is more relevant now :)

Comment: @Mansfield the [Giant S](http://i.imgur.com/fnfUk.png) will always be relevant around here.