# Stackoverflow in Arabic

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Other language localization](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/other-language-localization)

I'd like to see stackoverflow functionality in Arabic. A lot of Arabian programmers and designers have expressed their interests to use a stackoverflow-functionality-type, where all the users exchange their questions and discussions. Arabic is a tough language to implement due to its nature of reading and writing from right to left, similar to Hebrew, Persian, Urdu...etc. Maybe I'm asking too much, but it is fun dreaming :)

Comment: Here is the arabic-stackoverflow proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58628/stackoverflow-in-arabic?referrer=ExJyjI9UDfX3kIuW__R2Mw2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-overflow-around-the-world/

> So we’re depending on you to tell us how we should launch versions of Stack Overflow in languages other than English. If you speak another language fluently and think that the world would benefit from Stack Exchanges in that language, propose them [on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).