# StackExchange localization, again

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Localization: The state of the nation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82176/localization-the-state-of-the-nation)

I want to ask it again, **when**?  I read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/other-language-localization) and [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-overflow-funding-chat-qa-transcript/) and answered definitely yes, but it was year ago. Any progress on the subject. And I mean not to localize only Stack Overflow or any existent Stack Exchange site, but any proposed Q&A site.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a site in [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) that is for a different language group, then just rally supporters for the cause.

Like [this one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34468/applying-to-foreign-colleges-universities-in-chinese).

Comment: This is not really what he asks about, is it?

Comment: @Pekka, I have no idea why you say that.  The Area51 site will allow exactly what he asks for.

Comment: If I understand him correctly, he's talking about localizing the *UI* - but I can be wrong

Comment: That would be one way of looking at it I suppose, but he's not really clear about it.